# How do I return the image list from the Laravel API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, file

***How do I return the image list from the Laravel API?
I want to send images from the API as a collection. How can I do it? 
I would like to do it using ProductCollection resource if possible.
Thank you from now.***

***I would like to fetch the file data from this:***

```
   {
   "data": [
   {
   "id": 20,
   "name": "Cali Howe",
   "price": "4.00",
   "imageUrl": "C:\\Shop\\shop.api\\public\\img/default.png",
   "category_name": "Consequuntur ut.",
   "detail": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/20"
   },
   {
   "id": 19,
   "name": "Annie Murazik",
   "price": "13.00",
   "imageUrl": "C:\\Shop\\shop.api\\public\\img/default.png",
   "category_name": "Consequuntur ut.",
   "detail": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/19"
   }
   ],
   "links": {
   "first": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product?page=1",
   "last": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product?page=10",
   "prev": null,
   "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product?page=2"
   },
   "meta": {
   "current_page": 1,
   "from": 1,
   "last_page": 10,
   "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product",
   "per_page": 2,
   "to": 2,
   "total": 20
   }
   }
```

***Product Controller:***

```
public function index()
{
    return ProductCollection::collection(Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(2));
}
```

***Product Collection:***

```
class ProductCollection extends JsonResource
{
     public function toArray($request)
     {
         return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'imageUrl' => $this->imagePath('default.png'),
            'category_name' => $this->category->name,
            'detail' => route('product.show', $this->id),
        ];
     }
}
```

***Product Model:***

```
class Product extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function imagePath($fileName)
{
    return public_path('img/' . $fileName);
}
}
```

***Product Migration:***

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('name')->index();
        $table->decimal('price')->default(0);
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
            ->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What happens when you run the code you have provided? I have not tested it, but from the looks of it, you are on the right track by using resource collection. Try to describe your problem a little better and explain what issues you have faced with your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the image to base64

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents("/path/to/image.jpg");
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
```

Edited

```
class ProductCollection extends JsonResource
{
     public function toArray($request)
     {
         return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'imageUrl' => $this->imagePath('default.png'),
            'category_name' => $this->category->name,
            'detail' => route('product.show', $this->id),
            'base64' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->imagePath('default.png')),
        ];
     }
}
```

Comment: return image data: 45216 characters. This is a problem. What should I do? @ujiriukiri